# Creating column names with "(" in hive 1.1.0

Tags: hive

I tried to create table in hive as below:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS department(deptid int, deptname(1) string, deptname(2) string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile;
```

I am getting error as

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:58 cannot recognize input near '(' '1' ')' in column type

Is there any other way to create columns with "("

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`** (*backtick*) to escape **(** (*round bracket*).

It can be used for both tables names and fields names.

Try:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS department(`deptid` int, `deptname(1)` string, `deptname(2)` string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' stored as textfile;
```